# find and Remove from IList

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I have a IList of users

```
private IList<User> _Players
```

I have a method to remove a specific user from the list

```
public virtual void RemovePlayer(User User)
{
    int index=_Players.Select(T=>T.ID).ToList().IndexOf(User.ID);
    _Players.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

I would like to know if there is a simpler way to remove a user from this list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two scenarios, the `user` variable that you are passing to `RemovePlayer`

1. is actually contained in your list
2. has the same `ID` value, but is not the same object.

From your code sample it is impossible to say.

For the first case just call `_Players.Remove(user)`. For the second case implement the  [`System.IEquatable<User>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) interface on `User` to define a default `EqualityComparer<User>` and then again call `_Players.Remove(user)`. This second scenario works in both cases.

Comment: this solution helps alot because I'm using generics and I can remove objects without the need to know the properties they contain.

Comment: @David On SO people vote based primarily on the poster's score rather than the answer; that is well evidenced here :)

Answer (score 13):

How about this? Use this if your parameter `User` is not part of `_Players`.

```
 _Players.Remove(_Players.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == User.ID));
```

The `SingleOrDefault()` ensures that if the match is not found, that null is returned. When trying to remove null, no err occurs or is thrown.

Answer (score 9):

If the `User` objects you use are held within the _`Players` list (same object references) you can just do

```
_Players.Remove(user);
```

Otherwise if only the id matches you can do:

```
_Players.RemoveAll( p => p.ID == user.ID);
```

Comment: RemoveAll doesn't work on IList, which was the original question.

Comment: This answer does not apply to the original question.

Answer (score 5):

Depends, if you have implemented `IEquatable` on your user to compare by the `ID`, then you could simply do `_Players.Remove(user)`.

Otherwise:

```
var doomed = _Players.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == user.ID);
if (doomed != null)
   _Players.Remove(doomed);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Only in case if you have `List<T>`:**

All the mentioned algorithms with `SingleOrDefault()` / `FirstOrDefault()` require two traversals among list:

1) first one to find an item by criteria

2) second one to find index of item by its value found in step #1

It's a bit more efficient to do like this instead:

```
int index = list.FindIndex(i => criteria);

if (index >= 0)
  list.RemoveAt(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to do the same, but couldn't find a standard way. 
Decided to go code it myself for my int lists.
This little one won't do double-pass on the list!
You can replace `int` with `object` to work with classes.

```cs
public static bool FindAndRemoveFirst(this ICollection<int> list, Func<int, bool> predicate)
{
    var en = list.GetEnumerator();
    while (en.MoveNext())
    {
        if (predicate(en.Current))
        {
            list.Remove(en.Current);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```